# Is there any nice printing function for Table?

Tags: java, printing, guava

I wanted to print stuff to screen, but I have to iterate over every time and it's not nice.
So wondering if anybody has a printing function for Tables ?

Comment: Do you have an example of the output you want to achieve?

Comment: what is Table in your case and what data you want to print?

Comment: @smas: Given the `guava` tag, this probably refers to the Guava interface `Table`.

Comment: well, I just want to print strings and numbers (the printable things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Table implementations in Guava have reasonable toString() behavior, if that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something which output the integer and strings in the table in a nice format.
I end up writing it myself.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

use this library.you can print your details in tables.

https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view